# Binary operator - cannot be applied to operands of type String! and Int

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write the following line of code in swift:

```
 objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter integerValue]-1];
```

i tried :

```
    objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter = objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter - 1
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
Binary operator - cannot be applied to operands of type String! and Int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter` output value is `String` and you have to convert it to `Int` before use `-` operator

```
if let count = Int(objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter) {
    objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter = String(count - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error says that you are trying to do **subtraction by 1** from a **string value**, basically which is not possible.

So, first make the bellow **string** to **int**

**objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter**

and then subtract by 1

Answer (score 0):

To have exactly the same code written in Swift you should do:

```
objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter = NSString(format: "%ld", objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter.integerValue - 1)
```

In your original code you have this bit:

```
[objManager.userObject.free_credit_counter integerValue]
```

It converts the `NSString` value of `free_credit_counter` to an integer, which is then decremented by 1, and then the result is converted back to `NSString` using a format mask.

In the Swift code that you have posted in the question, the conversion to integer is missing.  That's what the error tells you about

Comment: I'm getting : `value of type String has no member integerValue.`

Comment: In this case you are using not `NSString` but `String` which is different type.  Your code is already different from what is in Objective-C then.  If you already make changes to it, you better use `Int` instead of `String` and only convert it to `String` when it's needed (on the UI, for example).